Nested Lists (in R): Assign a value to a nested list from a list with a single value and the same structure
Suppose there are two lists; my_List_B will always have a single element that either

will be present in my_List_A or,
is to be added to my_List_A

Is there a simple way to change my_List_A with the value in my_List_B according to the rules?
The only solutions that I have involve map and recursion. That's a tricky business for something that should be simple.
my_list_A <- list(
  level1 = list(
    item1 = 1,
    item2 = 2,
    sublist1 = list(
      subitem1 = "a",
      subitem2 = "b"
    )
  ),
  level2 = list(
    item3 = 3,
    item4 = 4,
    sublist2 = list(
      subitem3 = "c",
      subitem4 = "d"
    )
  )
)


my_list_B <- list(
  level1 = list(
    sublist1 = list(
      subitem2 = "c")
  )
)


Please see ?modifyList

Please show your approach and the desired result. What is the difference between A and B after the opreation?

Dear @ismirsehregal. Thanks. I was sure that a simpler method existed :). That's it!
